# how to retrieve and store a list of lists extracted from a list by partial string match?

Tags: python

I'm trying to pull out all the lines from a text file (which is a list of lines) that occur between list items containing the string 'Chapter '.

My data, `content_lines`, looks like this:

```
['Chapter 1', 'Sir Walter Elliot.....', 'Another paragraph of text.', 'And another....', 'Chapter 2', 'Paragraph starting chapter 2', 'Another paragraph in chapter 2']
```

I want to iterate over all the chapters and create a list of lists, where each list contains only the items between 'Chapter ' and 'Chapter '. So, something that looks like this:

```
[['Sir Walter Elliot.....', 'Another paragraph of text.', 'And another....'], ['Paragraph starting chapter 2', 'Another paragraph in chapter 2']]
```

So far, I have this:

```
l = content_lines
wanted = 'Chapter '


result = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(wanted) is False, l))
```

That gets me a list of all the lines that don't contain 'Chapter ', which is a good start, but it's not what I'm looking for. I'm new to this, and I know I'll have to create a loop of some kind, but my searches just aren't working for me. Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try iterating and creating your output:

```
output = list()
for line in content_lines:
    if line.startswith("Chapter"):
        output.append([])
    else:
        output[-1].append(line)

>>> output
[['Sir Walter Elliot.....', 'Another paragraph of text.', 'And another....'],
 ['Paragraph starting chapter 2', 'Another paragraph in chapter 2']]
```

Comment: @not_speshal-- that is great! And so much simpler than the backbends I was trying. This, I can wrap my head around. What is the [-1] in the output list for? Is that ensuring that the index is 0,1,2,3 and not 1,2,3? Oh, wait. It seems to be adding the nested list element. Why does it work that way? I think I get it, but not sure. Anyway, this works--thanks!!

Comment: The `output[-1]` refers to last element in `output`. So if the line doesn't start with "Chapter", just append it to last element.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, hope it helps.

```
list = ['Chapter 1', 'Sir Walter Elliot.....', 'Another paragraph of text.', 'And another....', 'Chapter 2', 'Paragraph starting chapter 2', 'Another paragraph in chapter 2']

i = 0
res = []

for x in list:
    if "Chapter" in x:
        i+=1
        res.append([])
    else:
        res[i-1].append(x)
        
print(res)
```